# Downloading file from a variable thats passed from another class to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, download

> I am trying to download files from my controller. I am receiving a variable from from a different class and need to download what is on that variable. I know I am probably doing a lot wrong right now. Any guidance would help a lot
>   **Here is my class and I am returning the value allPaths**

```
public class DBQueries 
{

    public List<string> GetSpecificYears(string[] response)
    {
        List<string> allPaths = new List<string>();

        if (response != null)
        {
            using (var db = new ....())
            {
                foreach (var aYear in response)
                {
                    // access a DbSet from DbContext here!
                    List<string> paths = db.ClientStatement_Inventory
                                           .Where(x => x.statementYear == aYear)
                                           .Select(y => y.statementPath).ToList();

                    allPaths.AddRange(paths);
                }
            }
        }
        return allPaths;
    }
}
```

}

> **I am then passing allPaths variable to my controller by setting var allYears = getyears.GetSpecificYears()**
>   Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult ExportFile(string[] years, string[] months, string[]radio, string[] acctNum)
    {

        ClientStatement_Inventory theStatementPath = new ClientStatement_Inventory();
        var thePath = theStatementPath.statementPath;

        DBQueries getyears = new DBQueries();
        var allYears = getyears.GetSpecificYears(years);


        var document = new ClientStatement_Inventory();

        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = document.statementYear,

            Inline = false,
        };

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        return File(document.statementPath, document.statementYear);
```

> How can I download these files using the allyears variable that is holding all the info?

Comment: Do you want to download all files containing in `years` in one request?

Comment: @Dmitry yeah that is kinda what i was going for.. download all of them in a zip file.